# How to delete a row in a dataframe based on a column event with consecutive same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, the below is a data frame:

```
   Index      Name       Action
    0          result    pass
    1          result    fail
    2          result    fail
    3          result    pass
    4          result    fail
    5          result    pass
    6          result    pass
    7          result    pass
```

Here we are taking reference of "Action" column, consecutive 'pass' or 'fail' will result only last one of the row to be present.

so expected output will be as below:

```
   Index      Name       Action
    0          result    pass
    2          result    fail
    3          result    pass
    4          result    fail
    7          result    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `-1` for mask for last rows and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Action'].ne(df['Action'].shift(-1))]
print (df)
     Name Action
0  result   pass
2  result   fail
3  result   pass
4  result   fail
7  result   pass
```